# Do spaces with equivalent fundamental group share the same Universal Cover

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Just the question above. I have not been able to find a clear answer for this.

I am leaning towards yes but want to be sure.

Comment: No, if you have two spaces $X$ and $Y$ with the same fundamental group but with different higher homotopy groups their covering spaces won't be homotopy equivalent since the universal cover $C$ of a space $Z$ shares the higher homotopy groups with $Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S^1$ has fundamental group $\mathbb Z$, and universal cover $\mathbb R$.

$S^1\times[0,1]$ also has fundamental group $\mathbb Z$, and has universal cover $\mathbb R\times[0,1]$.

---

Answer to the follow-up: Not all simply connected spaces (these have trivial fundamental group and are its own universal cover) are homotopy-equivalent: $S^2$ and $[0,1]$.

Comment: The follow-up would be: do spaces with the same fundamental group have homotopy-equivalent universal covers?

Comment: Can we use universal covers of homotopy equivalent spaces to help construct the other universal cover? For example, a 2-sphere with a line through the diameter and the wedge of a 2-sphere and circle.

Comment: And the follow-up to the follow-up is whether homotopy-equivalent spaces have homotopy-equivalent universal covers. This is more difficult and is Hatcher, Exercise 1.3.8.